# Styling a php variable in css using the <p> tags

Tags: php, html, css

I am having lots of trouble trying to style a php variable within a css file. I am coding a simple exercise type website, but am stumped on what to do. I have made a log in system and I want the user's username to appear in the corner every time they log in. Here is my code

```
<!--header.php-->
<header>
    <nav>
        <div class="mainWrapper">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="forum.php">Forums</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="navLogin">
                <?php
                    if (isset($_SESSION['u_id'])) {
                        echo '<p class="navUsername">'.$_SESSION['u_uid'].'</p><form action="Includes/logout.inc.php" method="POST">
                    <button type="submit" name="submit">Logout</button>
                </form>';
                    } else {
                        echo '<form method="POST" action="Includes/login.inc.php">
                    <input type="text" name="uid" placeholder="Username/Email">
                    <input type="password" name="pwd" placeholder="Password">
                    <button type="submit" name="submit">Sign In</button>
                </form><a href="Includes/signup.inc.php">Sign Up</a>';
                    };
                ?>

            </div>              
        </div>
    </nav>
</header>
```

and now the css:

```
.navUsername {
font-size: 100px;}
```

I have researched online and they say to put the css within a php file, but in their examples they are using the variable as a parameter rather than styling the variable itself.

Comment: Can you please clarify what specific `HTML` element you are trying to style with `CSS`?

Comment: wen you say "appear in the corner every time" you mean one time like "Hello Mr. Phooey" and then it disappears like a pop up message or that the username is constantly in the upper right corner?

Comment: I'd strongly recommend looking at learning a framework like larvel, although you can continue to write code like this, it is very much an approach we used 5-10 years ago, and to be quite frank it's kinda messy and hard to maintain (made the same mistake when I first started learning web dev 6 years ago)...in regards to your question, are you sure the css file is being loaded?  There is no reason to put the styles inline in your php file, they can remain abstracted in their respective CSS files.

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually have an element in your code that has the `.navUsername` class. I **assume** you're trying to target `<input type="text" name="uid" placeholder="Username/Email">`.

You can target this element with the `name` [**attribute selector**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors):

```css
input[name="uid"] {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="uid" placeholder="Username/Email">
```

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

I’m assuming this is the element you are wanting to style:

```
echo '<p class="navUsername">'.$_SESSION['u_uid'].'</p>
```

Is the name actually appearing, and just not being styled, or is the name not appearing at all?

**If the name is appearing:**
Change the CSS to:

```
p.navUsername {
  font-size: 100px;
}
```

**If the name is not appearing:**
Has the php session been started on this page with

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
```